# Symfony 4 Why my "make:migration" command not work?

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony4

I execute this:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

I have this error :

```
    In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Une tentative de connexion a chou car le parti connect na pas rpondu convenablemen  
  t au-del dune certaine dure ou une connexion tablie a chou car lhte de connexion na pas rpondu.                                        


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Une tentative de connexion a chou car le parti connect na pas rpondu convenablement au-del dune certaine dure ou  
   une connexion tablie a chou car lhte de connexion na pas rpondu.                                                                         


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Une tentative de connexion a chou car le parti connect na pas rpondu convenablement au-del dune certaine dure ou  
   une connexion tablie a chou car lhte de connexion na pas rpondu.
```

I have a existing database, and I just add a table in PhpMySql, after that I want refresh my entities

Can you help me please ?

Comment: The error means your DB connection is not set correctly or you database is not available.

Comment: my DATABASE_URL is setup like this DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@db_host/db_name  and I use this logs to connect on my PhpMyAdmin successfully

Answer (score 2):

This is because maybe your environment is the production and this command will only work on the development environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, @mxsxs2 is right.

This error message shows that your database is not responding, so usually it can mean two things.

- Database is down
- You set the wrong credentials

You said that you use

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@db_host/db_name
```

But try to replace `db_host` with `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. Make sure that your database is named `db_name`, that your user is `db_user` and the password is `db_password`. It should works.

---

**EDIT**

There is also an other known "problem", only on mac and specially MAMP which use `8889` port for MySQL instead of classic `3306`

Comment: This is not solving the problem